# C Parser for parsing and reading Config file with defined format?

Tags: c, parsing

I need to parse a configuration file , I need to compare the string variable and get the values.

The variable and values are seperated by white spaces,
For example,
TestscenConf.config file contains the following,

```
SCENARIO_TYPE    WIRELESS_TEST
SIMULATION_TIME  200
[1] [IP_ADDR1][1] 192.168.1.0
[2] [IP_ADDR2][1] 192.168.1.2
[2] [IP_ADDR2][2] 192.168.1.3
```

Here, everything is seperated by space.

I want to compare variable name and get its value.

How can I parse it in C or C++.

Thank you,

Arun

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use one of this *scanf() functions, but i strongly suggest you to use common open standart for your configs (such as XML or JSON). it's much better because of many reasons:

1) You get stable working parser for any OS and any programming language. Just take a look at JSON:
http://www.json.org/ - how many languages are supported!

2) What happens if you add one another item in you config? or item of other format (list of ip-addresses, for example)? Take universal, ubiquitous solution!

Comment: +1 While I agree with you (using a standard for data is a good thing), that implies changes to the input file.

Answer (score 0):

[fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html), ([fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html), [sscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sscanf.html), and [strcmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html)) in a loop, and [fclose](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fclose.html) come to mind.